# Is it possible to use substrings without having to store them in a seperate variable

Tags: python, string

I want to be able to check what the first substring in the string: `random_string = "fox is bright orange"` is without needing to split the string and then read from the list, or store it some other variable. Is it possible to do this?

the string I am using here is just an example, so there is not a designated string being used. I want to be able to figure out the substring (if it were split by `' '`) of **any** string without having to use a list

Comment: What do you mean "the first substring"?

Comment: @heemayl I have tried googling for it, or just how to check for substrings without having to do anything to the string. But other than that, no. Mainly because I do not know what to try or how to approach this

Comment: @kindall if the string were split by `' ' ` then the first element of the list is what I mean by the first substring

Comment: When you split the string, it creates a new list, it does not mutate the string to a list if that is what you fear. Why do you want to avoid split?

Comment: @Olivier it is not what I fear. I am trying to find a way to do this without using lists

Comment: Why, why do you not want to use list?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I am trying to minimize the amount of variables I use and I thought that removing the use of lists would be plausible

Comment: Why are you trying to minimize the number of variables you use? Can you show an example of some code that you think has too many variables?

Comment: @DanielPryden it's not what I have but is what I am going to have. There will be a lot of variables involved and the list (if i do you it) would contain a huge number of substrings. And to not lose spead even at the slightest, I would want to avoid it

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. If you have too many local variables, that's not a *problem*, that's a *symptom*: it probably means that you aren't using enough functions. And "lose spead even at the slightest" is completely incomprehensible to me. Show your *actual* problem, and that will allow us to help you find an actual solution.

Comment: This question is an [X-Y problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) if I've ever seen one!

Comment: @DanielPryden I get where your going by it being an X-Y problem, but all I need was for a way to not use lists and to be able to get sub strings without creating lists. The reason for why I am doing this shouldn't affect the answers given (at least for me it doesn't). Many people already gave me answers which thoroughly answered my question

Comment: But the point of Stack Overflow isn't for *you* to get what you need, it's to build a repository of knowledge that is useful to others. This question as it stands is not useful to others. I'm not even convinced that it is in fact useful to you: I think reworking your approach is likely to be *much more* useful to you (in terms of readability, performance, and correctness), but if you're dead set on not getting help then I guess there's nothing I can do to help you!

Comment: @DanielPryden I am trying hard to understand your concern, but I always thought that creating a question with an example that isnt just targeted for me is most helpful for everyone else. I am not using a definite string, I am not needing a solution that can only work with certain code, but all I am asking is for a solution that just works. I am deeply sorry if I am frustrating you, I truly am. But there is nothing I am really trying to hide

Comment: @DanielPryden Op is right with his/her concern about processing the whole string if he needs the first three letters in a million letter string (if that's the only concern). I couldn't speak for the rest of the problem of course, which I don't know.

Comment: The first substring is of course `''`. Always.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you want to get `fox` from `fox is bright orange`:

1. Regex; `^\w+` gets one or more alphanumerics from start:

   ```
   In [61]: re.search(r'^\w+', random_string).group()
   Out[61]: 'fox'
   ```
2. `str.partition` (which produces a tuple) and getting the first element

   ```
   In [62]: random_string.partition(' ')[0]
   Out[62]: 'fox'
   ```

Comment: could you explain how the regex one works? I am a bit confused

Comment: @exemplarary Added explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do what you want in Python is exactly what you are trying to avoid. There is no real reason to do this.

But... if you absolutely want to avoid using a list, you can do this.

```
sub_string = random_string[:random_string.index(' ')]
```

Note that this will raise an exception if there is no space in your string.

Comment: I suppose if the string happens to be the Encyclopedia Britannica a case could be made for avoiding the list.

Comment: I don't see any problem with loading a 4gb string in memory and then making a list of out of it.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to check whether a given string begins with a certain word?

```
random_string = "fox is bright orange"
print(random_string.startswith("fox ")   # True
```

Do you want to get the length of the first word?

```
random_string = "fox is bright orange"
print(random_string.index(" "))           # 3
```

Do you want to get the first word, but not split anything else?

```
random_string = "fox is bright orange"
print(random_string[:random_string.index(" ")])    # fox
```

Note that `str.index()` raises `ValueError` when the specified substring isn't found, i.e. when there's only one word in the string, so if you use one of the last two solutions, you should catch that error and do something appropriate (such as using the whole string).

```
random_string = "fox is bright orange"
try:
    print(random_string[:random_string.index(" ")])
except ValueError:
    print(random_string)
```

Or you could use `str.find()` instead. This returns -1 when the substring isn't found, which you would have to handle a little differently.

Comment: Please note that, if someone wants to do this without error handling (for whatever reason), this should work `random_string[:(random_string + " ").index(" ")]` (Adding a space to the end in the search).

Comment: I was trying to avoid creating new strings, as this seems important, but you're right, I've often used that very approach.

Comment: You are right of course, as creating new strings is expensive. This method is for people more like "I like small, clever Python one-liners". Which is still legit for some cases :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use slicing:

```
In [1]: s = "fox is bright orange"

In [2]: s[4:7]
Out[2]: 'is '

In [3]: s[4:13]
Out[3]: 'is bright'

In [4]: s[4:]
Out[4]: 'is bright orange'

In [6]: s[:6]
Out[6]: 'fox is'
```

In lower level languages (like C) you could have pointers on the original string with arbitraty offests. So you could replicate this behaviour using slices. However please note that python will always return a copy anyways, because python string are immutable.

Comment: Is there a way to do this so that It isn't necessary for me to know the size of the string to pin point what I need. Because the strings will be different and wont use the same positions for characters

Comment: Could you please provide an example input and the desired output? Because there are many ways to do that and your question is not clear enough. Please edit.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use re, how about simple iteration over the `random_string`?

```
def get_first_word(long_string):
    offset = 0
    while long_string[offset] !=" ":
        offset+=1

    return long_string[0:offset]
```

So running this code:

```
random_string = "fox is bright orange"
print(get_first_word(random_string))
```

will print - `fox`

Answer (score 0):

This

```
''.join(iter(iter(s).__next__, ' '))
```

will work regardless of whether there actually is a `' '` in your string or not.