# Why does str.find return -1 when no substring is found?

Tags: python, string

In another [question that asks how to get the first word of a string without using str.split](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48917405/is-it-possible-to-use-subtrings-without-having-to-store-them-in-a-seperate-varia/48917496?noredirect=1#comment84841882_48917496), a few users came up with the following idea.

```
word = s[:s.find(' ')]
```

It works whenever the string `s` contains a space. Although this silently fails if it does not contain one.

```
s = 'foo'
word = s[:s.find(' ')] # 'fo'
```

This is due to the fact that `str.find` returns `-1` when the substring is not found.

This seems to be a weird design choice for the following reasons.

1. `-1` is actually a correct index
2. Interpreted as a `bool`, it does not have any useful meaning in the
   context
3. `None` would seem to be a way better candidate (and would make the above code work)

Is there a good design reason or use case why `-1` was chosen as the return value for `str.find` instead of `None` when there is no substring found?

Comment: Seems like leaked C/C++ API there.

Comment: I was under this impression as well, but I feel CPython developpers have made very good design choices overall, especially since Python3, so I am surprised and wondering if I am not missing a good use case here.

Comment: Not sure you'll get a definitive answer from any mailing archive, but here's [a small quip from Guido van Rossum](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2005-August/055740.html) about `str.find`.

Comment: @miradulo this is the kind of information I am after, thank you

Comment: @Olivier No problem. I remember once digging around in source code looking for a comment with reasoning for -1 vs. None, but didn't come up with anything.

Comment: Actually, an important question is: what came first? None or str.find? I was able to find that None appeared in version 2.2.1. What about str.find?

Comment: I have not checked when it was created, however, it was already present around Python 2.0: https://docs.python.org/2.0/lib/string-methods.html

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for brining up this question as I was surprised [the showcase of find examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674764/examples-for-string-find-in-python) does not mention this problem. I agree with your reasoning that and I have been unable to find specific justification for such an important implementation decision.

If you take a look at [the find method](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/7e30821b17b56bb5ed9799f62eb45e448cb52c8e/Objects/stringlib/find.h#L8) and its most significant implementation component, [fastsearch](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/7e30821b17b56bb5ed9799f62eb45e448cb52c8e/Objects/stringlib/fastsearch.h#L750), you will see that it returns `-1` when unable to locate the substring, as stated in the documentation. There are no, however, indications in the code explaining why it is written in such a way. Interestingly, one of the comments includes a warning about that return value, suggesting that the developers were aware of this detail being a quirk.

### Why is it a problem?

Imagine you have strings that contain lowercase spaceless company name-based ids that may end with `inc`, which you would like to remove to normalise them.

In a typical scenario, you could do:

```py
s = "fastcareinc"
idx = s.find("inc")
>>> s[:idx]
'fastcare'
```

However, if the name is already in your normalised form, you would end up with a severe bug that leads to a misrepresentation of the id:

```py
s = "fastcare"
idx = s.find("inc")
>>> s[:idx]
'fastcar'
```

Above, the name has been altered from `"fastcare"` to `"fastcar"`, because the variable `idx` is `-1`, thus slicing removes the last character from `s`. If `str.find` returned `None`, that would not be a problem:

```py
s = "fastcare"
idx = None
>>> s[:idx]
'fastcare'
```

The best way to resolve this issue would be to voice it in the Python community with a PR to cPython. For now, however, I would suggest you to use `str.index` in lieu of `str.find` to avoid such situations in production code. Alternatively, I propose a workaround that would keep you away from that bug, based on the outlined scenario:

```py
>>> s[:None if (idx := s.find("inc")) == -1 else idx]
'fastcare'
```